# Nesting for-loop in Order to Create Brick Wall

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am new to programming and this is my first time posting to this site. I am currently working on an assignment which will allow a user to input a number between 1 and 20, and then will create a brick wall based upon the number of brick layers the user entered into the JTextField. I was able to create one row, but I don't really understand nesting statements, and all of the examples I've looked at on the web just confuse me more, so I was wondering if someone could possibly help me to better understand nesting for-loops.

```
//Package List
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Wall extends JApplet implements KeyListener {



//Component declaration
    JLabel directions;
    JTextField input;
    //Variable declaration
    int startX = 50;
    int startY = 650;
    int width = 50;
    int height = 20;
    int spacing = 2;


    //Method declaration
    public void init() 
    {
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color (128, 128, 128));//Changes backround of JApplet to black
        //Set JTextField and JLabel
        setLayout (new FlowLayout( ));
        directions = new JLabel("Enter in any number between 1 and 20 and then press Enter on your keyboard.");
        input = new JTextField ( 10 );
        add (directions );
        add (input);

        //Key listener
        addKeyListener( this );
        setFocusable( true );   
    }

    //Method declaration 
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paint (g);

        for (int col=1; col<= 8; col++)
         {
         // for (int row; row<=20; row++)
            {   g.setColor (Color.RED);
                g.fillRect (startX, startY, 50, 20);
                startX =  startX + spacing + width;
            }

         }
    }

    //Key event methods
    public void keyReleased( KeyEvent ke ){}
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent ke ) {}
    public void keyPressed ( KeyEvent ke )
    {
        int key = ke.getKeyCode ( );    
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {
        }

    }
```

Comment: You need to step the x and y values accordingly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the `x`/`y` position of the brick based on the current `row`/`col`.  Now, you could simply initialise these values at the start of each loop and increment as required, or you could use a little maths...

[image: Bricks]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AnotherBrickInTheWall extends JApplet {

//Component declaration
    JLabel directions;
    JTextField input;
    //Variable declaration
    int startX = 0;
    int startY = 50;
    int width = 50;
    int height = 20;
    int spacing = 2;

    //Method declaration
    public void init() {
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(128, 128, 128));//Changes backround of JApplet to black
        //Set JTextField and JLabel
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        directions = new JLabel("Enter in any number between 1 and 20 and then press Enter on your keyboard.");
        input = new JTextField(10);
        add(directions);
        add(input);
    }

    //Method declaration 
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            int y = startY + (row * (height + spacing));
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                int x = startX + (col * (width + spacing));
                System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you should never paint on a component which has components added to, this will cause the painting to appear over the top of the components and end up with all sorts of painting issues.

Instead, create a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method instead and place your custom painting here.

You could then add your controls another `JPanel` and using a `BorderLayout` on your applet, add these two panels, the fields in the `NORTH` position and wall in the `CENTER` position

**Updated**

If you wanted to get "really" fancy, you could even adjust the `x` position based on the current `row`, for example...

[image: Bricks]

```
int xOffset = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    int y = startY + (row * (height + spacing));
    if (row % 2 == 0) {
        xOffset = width / 2;
    } else {
        xOffset = 0;
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
        int x = xOffset + (startX + (col * (width + spacing)));
        System.out.println(x + "x" + y);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

Also, `JTextField` is has an `ActionListener` which is triggered when the field is actioned, typically by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This means that you shouldn't need the `KeyListener`.

See [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more details.

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast! Thank you for your help! Could you recommend any books on programming?

Comment: There are tons of books, one of the more common and general might be Effective Java and you might find [these suggestions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155659/java-language-book-for-an-experienced-programmer) useful

Answer (score 0):

```
int x=num //1-20
int step=num/8;
int last_row=num%8;
for(int j=1;j<=step;j++){
    int nos=8;
    if(j == step && last_step ! = 0)
        nos = last_step;
    for (int col=1; col<= nos; col++)
    {
        g.setColor (Color.RED);
        g.fillRect (startX, startY, 50, 20);
        startX =  startX + spacing + width;
        startY =  startY*j;
    }
}
```

Try this.